# Компилятор в "Программирование на C++ глазами хакера" Фленов М.Е.

Tags: книги, c++

Подскажите, какой компилятор использует автор этой книги. И если не трудно, дайте сылку...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У него стоит версия Microsoft Visual Studio.NET, но все проекты можно открыть [Visual Studio  2010](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/ru-ru/download).

Answer (score 2):

Если не ошибаюсь VC++ 6 (или VC++ состава Visual Studio 2003), на одном из них в свое время изучал эти проекты.
Бесплатная версия [Microsoft Visual Studio](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio) Express доступна для скачивания в [официальном сайте](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/ru-ru/products/2010-editions/express), скорее всего в ней тоже можно открыть эти проекты.

Comment: в ней можно открыть проекты, она всегда ставить .NET с собой